# Throttling issue while listing Azure Storage Accounts

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-java-sdk, azure-sdk

I am using Azure JAVA SDK and am trying to list the Storage Accounts for the subscription. But I am intermittently getting this exception response.

> com.microsoft.azure.CloudException: Status code 429,
>   {"error":{"code":"ResourceCollectionRequestsThrottled","message":"Operation
>   'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/read' failed as server encountered
>   too many requests. Please try after '17' seconds. Tracking Id is
>   'f13c3318-8fb3-4ae1-85a5-975f4c17a512'."}}

Is there a limit on the number of requests one can make to the Azure resource API ?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a limit on the number of requests one can make to the Azure
>   resource API ?

Yes. The limits are documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits (please see `Subscription limits - Azure Resource Manager` section). And you can see the `429` error code from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/srp_error_codes_common).

Based on the documentation, currently you're allowed to make `15000 Read requests/hour` for `Azure Resource Manager API`.

Comment: Surprisingly it just fails while only making a request to get a list of Storage Accounts.

Comment: That is weird. Are you able to perform other ARM operations like list resource groups without any problem?

Comment: These are the sequence of events which I do and every time it fails on the second operation while listing the Storage Accounts .Not even once it failed on the first operation.                                          azure.virtualMachines().list();
azure.storageAccounts().list();

Comment: Honestly I don't know why this is happening. It may be a good idea to post this issue as a comment here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-request-limits. You will get to hear from product team directly. HTH.

Comment: I get the same:  Operation 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/read' failed as server encountered too many requests. Please try after '17' seconds.   It's weird that is **'17' seconds always** , my operation is a az storage blob delete, but is not even 15 operations per minute.

Comment: Storage account management operations have a more strict throttling limit than the overall ARM throttling.  For storage account list operations the limit is 100 per 5 minutes.  These are documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits under the "Storage account management operations" section